# How to pass register to React Hook Forms Factory Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to create a "factory" of sorts so:
This works:

```
<>
  <span className={classes.p}>{"test"}</span>
  <input ref={register} className={classes.input} name="legal_name_1" />
</>
```

But when I wrap the input in a function in a component it does not work:

```
const MyInput = ({ name, register, ...props }) => {
 return (
  <>
  <span className={classes.p}>{AllDisasterAppFields[name]}</span>
  <input ref={register} className={classes.input} name={name} {...props} />
  </>
 );
};

<MyInput register={register} name= name="legal_name_1" {...props} />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `name= name="legal_name_1"`? Btw what is `register`? Something created with `useRef` or `createRef`?

Comment: You have `name=` two times, maybe that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to pass `register` as a prop.
If I'm right so You have to write your code like this (Don't use `ref` property but this `{...register(name)}`):

```
 const MyInput = ({ name, register, ...props }) => {
       return (
          <>
          <span className={classes.p}>{AllDisasterAppFields[name]}</span>
          <input {...register(name)} className={classes.input} name={name} {...props} />
      </>
     );
    };
    
<MyInput register={register} name="legal_name_1" {...props} />
```